# What is the initiation process for the Dvaita sampradaya? In what aspects does it differ from the Panchasamskara done by Srivaishnavas?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, dvaita, initiation, madhwa

I was hearing a upanyasam about the Taapa part of the panchasamskaram which comes under Samaashrayanam for Srivaishnavas. It was mentioned that Dvaitins also have a similar procedure but instead of donning the chakra and conch brands, they do it using sandalwood paste with flowers and do it everytime they visit their acharya. So, I would like to know how different the procedures of initiation are between the 2 sampradayas, given they both derive from pancaratra agamas.